0 th index wouldn't be able remove from the cart in Laravel
i use add json array for the add items to the cart. then values successfully added to the cart. but removing items, latest elemet (0th index element) wont able to delete from the cart
public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {
        $productId = $request->input('product_id');
        $product = Product::findOrFail($productId);


        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);

       
        $existingProductKey = null;
        foreach ($cart as $key => $item) {
            if ($item['id'] == $product->id) {
                $existingProductKey = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($existingProductKey !== null) {
            // Increase quantity if product already in cart
            $cart[$existingProductKey]['qty'] += 1;
        } else {
     
            $cart[] = [
                'id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'price' => $product->price,
                'image' => $product->image, // Assuming image field exists
                'qty' => 1,
            ];
        }

     
        session()->put('cart', $cart);


        return redirect()->route('cart');
    }


    public function showCart()
    {
        // Get cart from session
        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);
        return view('cart', compact('cart'));
    }


    public function removeFromCart(Request $request)
    {
        $productId = $request->input('product_id');

        // Get cart from session
        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);


        foreach ($cart as $key => $item) {
            if ($item['id'] == $productId) {
                unset($cart[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }

 
        $cart = array_values($cart);

        // Save updated cart back to session
        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->route('cart');
    }

this is the controller logic Items can add to the cart but when removing from cart wouldn't able to remove 0th index elemet from cart

Try this code
public function removeFromCart(Request $request)
{
$request->validate([
    'product_id' => 'required|integer',
]);

$productId = $request->input('product_id');
$cart = session()->get('cart', []);

$cart = array_filter($cart, function ($item) use ($productId) {
    return $item['id'] != $productId;
});

session()->put('cart', array_values($cart));

return redirect()->route('cart')->with('success', 'Product removed from cart!');
}

